# Eliminar modificación de la fecha en el input al hacer hover sobre los dias, DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Buenas, comento mi duda con mas detalle:

Al abrir el calendario puedes seleccionar una fecha de inicio y una fecha de fin, según vas pasando por los distintos días, en el input que almacena los rangos de las fechas dentro del calendario se va modificando el input mediante un hover.

Mi idea es eliminar que al pasar por encima de los dias no se muestre en el input.

Mi código:

```js
$(document).ready (function(){

 $("#exitoCarga").hide();
  $("#exitoEjecucion").hide();
  $("#mensajeReseteo").hide();

  $('#fechasCarga').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
  });
  
  $('#fechasEjecucion').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
  });

  $('#fechasCarga').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $('#fechaCargaInicio').val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
      $('#fechaCargaFin').val(picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
      $("#exitoCarga").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $("#exitoCarga").slideUp(500);
      });  
  });
  
  $('#fechasEjecucion').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $('#fechaEjecucionInicio').val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
      $('#fechaEjecucionFin').val(picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
      $("#exitoEjecucion").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $("#exitoEjecucion").slideUp(500);
      }); 
  });

  $('#fechasCarga').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });
  
  $('#fechasEjecucion').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });
  
  $('#resetearFechas').click(function() {
      $('#fechaCargaInicio').val("");
      $('#fechaCargaFin').val("");
      $('#fechaEjecucionInicio').val("");
      $('#fechaEjecucionFin').val("");
      $("#mensajeReseteo").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $("#mensajeReseteo").slideUp(500);
      }); 
  });

});
```

```css
.alerta {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #FF8000;
}

.alertaTexto {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px; 
}

.texto {
  color: #B45F04;
}
```

```html
<label class="texto" id="fechasCarga">Seleccionar fechas de carga</label>

<br>

<p>
  Fecha de carga(Inicio): <input type="text" id="fechaCargaInicio">
</p>
<p>
  Fecha de carga(Fin): <input type="text" id="fechaCargaFin">
</p>

<div class="alerta" id="exitoCarga">
  <label class="alertaTexto"><i><strong>¡Perfecto!</strong> Fechas de carga agregadas.</i></label>
</div>a

<br>

<label class="texto" id="fechasEjecucion">Seleccionar fechas de ejecucion</label>

<br>

<p>
  Fecha de ejecucion(Inicio): <input type="text" id="fechaEjecucionInicio">
</p>
<p>
  Fecha de ejecucion(Fin): <input type="text" id="fechaEjecucionFin">
</p>

<div class="alerta" id="exitoEjecucion">
  <label class="alertaTexto"><i><strong>¡Perfecto!</strong> Fechas de ejecución agregadas.</i></label>
</div>

<br>

<button type="button" id="resetearFechas">Resetear fechas</button>

<br>

<div class="alerta" id="mensajeReseteo">
  <label class="alertaTexto"><i><strong>¡Perfecto!</strong> Fechas reseteadas.</i></label>
</div>
```

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los input son de tipo texto, no se abre ningún calendario.

Comment: Pon tu código aquí, no es necesario crear un fiddle

Comment: El calendario se abre al darle al label "Seleccionar...", los input los utilizo para almacenar las fechas, perdonar por no aclararlo